# How do I write a function that repeatedly prompts the user for a number and then average the numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to programming, and I have no idea how to go about this.

Basically I need a function that repeatedly prompts a user to input an integer until they enter a non-numerical characters, then it takes the numbers and averages them.

This what I have so far, the ave function is to average the numbers, that's not the problem

```
def ioAve():
   L = input("Enter your number: ")
      if L == int:
         print(L)
      if L != int:
         ave(L)
```

The program doesn't return anything at all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP wants training, not 'how do I fix this?'

Comment: I see what the problem is, but you should really post what the observed behavior is, and how it diverges from the expected behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the most pythonic way I can think of to solve this.  Your approach of checking if an entered number is of a certain type is less desirable than catching the exceptions that might be raised when trying to convert (e.g. in this case a ValueError is raised when an invalid value is passed to int() ).  You can learn more about exceptions in Python at the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions).

The solution below also uses a list, which is an object that can contain multiple values.  You can learn more about lists at [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm).

```
numbers = list()
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        numbers.append(number)
    except ValueError:
        break

print ("The average is", sum(numbers) / len(numbers))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cont = True
nums = []
while cont:
    entered = input("Enter a number: ")
    cont = all(char.isdigit() for char in entered)
    if cont:
        nums.append(int(entered))
print("The average is:", sum(nums)/len(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe. I'm sure there is a more pythonic way thou.

```
#import sys instead of using sys for program termination

def main():
    sum = 0
    iterations = 0
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(raw_input("Input an integer: "))
            iterations += 1
            sum += num
        except:
            print "Average: "+str(sum//iterations)
            #sys.exit() use break to "jump" out of an infinite loop
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is C sneaked into Python. The most blatant Cism is the sys.exit() at the end of the function, the program will exit anyway when it is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
print('Average: ',(lambda x:sum(x)/len(x))
([x for x in iter(lambda:(lambda x:int(x)
if x and all(x.isdigit() for x in x)else
...)(input('Enter a number: ')),...)]))
```

Sorry, I couldn't resist.